# Re-Opening PostGIS Tab in Log Messages Panel

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I accidentally clicked the "X" next to PostGIS in the Log Messages Panel, and I cannot seem to find any way to open it again. I've checked most of the obvious settings dialogs and menus thinking this should be an easy fix, but I haven't been able to track down this particular item. I'm running QGIS v2.14.3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting up a new connection to a server that does not exist, or with a wrong port number or database name.

Next time you start QGIS, the `Postgis` tab will be gone, until there is need for another message from Postgis to be displayed.

Same goes for the `Network` and `CRS` tab.

Comment: so, the answer is do nothing, and the tab will come back on its own?